# Saving data in a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

I have a question on a possible way to save data while calling a method recursively.
I would like to save information in an `ArrayList` that holds a class called `ExpressionNode()`.

The process is: `<HOLDS Array>` `method1()` calls ``` <Create Array>``method2() ```, than `<ExpressionNode()-Info>` `method3()` is called which runs recursively.

My problem is that `method3()` runs recursively and while it runs I want to store info in `ExpressionNode()` and push it up to `method2()` but that won't happen since it overwrites that info each time its called again.

I can create a public `ArrayList` in the class but I am wondering if there is a better way to do so.

Comment: Just pass the list in as an argument to the recursive method.

Comment: use global variable..

Comment: more interesting question would be `should I pass it as an argument or use a global variable` :)

Comment: @arunmoezhi: That would make the question opinion-based.

Comment: @wiz3kid: you are right. But I just said it would be more interesting. I did not say it would fit into SO rules ;)

Comment: Thanks, I passed it in as an argument. But what would be the advantage over the other. Is it more efficient to just make a `global array list`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I think I got it.

What I did:

```
 private CompoundStatementNode compound_statement() {

    CompoundStatementNode answer = new CompoundStatementNode();
    answer.addAllArrayList(optional_statements());

    return answer;
}

private ArrayList<StatementNode> optional_statements() {

    ArrayList<StatementNode> answer = new ArrayList();

        statement_list(answer);
    return answer;
}

private ArrayList<StatementNode> statement_list(ArrayList<StatementNode> answer) {

    answer.add(statement());

    if (currentToken == PascalToken.SEMICOLON) {
        match(PascalToken.SEMICOLON);
        statement_list(answer);
    }

    return answer;
}
```